# Remove first column after "group by All rows" operationin Power Query

Tags: group-by, powerquery

I have an issue when trying to group by first column **Podrocje_dela** (PHASE 1). I use Group by All rows where second column has a name **Aktivnosti**.

***PHASE 1***

[image: Initial table with 2 text columns]

as the result is in two column format (PHASE 2), but I would like only last column, so the one marked with blue pen should be removed.

***PHASE 2***

[image: Table after group operation]

Why this is a problem? I need a first column items as column Names (red), but this names also appear as column values (blue) combined from 1st and 2nd column (PHASE 3), comma separated. I would need only second column values as shown in last image (PHASE 4).

***PHASE 3***

[image: Table where column names are items from first column in Phase2]

End result should be like is shown in image below (PHASE 4). This result is accomplished by .AfterDelimiter operation but as the number of different first column items (PHASE 1) can change it is not flexible enough.

***PHASE 4***

[image: Required final table]

For the end, I need result as shown in PHASE 4 from PHASE 1. Maybe my approach is not the best and I would be happy for any suggestions.

My current code is

```
let
Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("\\fs-srv01\PROJEKTI\S-DELOVNI-PROCES\DELOVNE URE\MS_Access\Podatkovne_baze\Organizacija.accdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
_tblPodrocja_dela = Source{[Schema="",Item="tblPodrocja_dela"]}[Data],
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(_tblPodrocja_dela,{"tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti"}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns",{"ID_Podrocje_dela"},tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti_M2M,{"ID_Podrocje_dela"},"tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti_M2M",JoinKind.FullOuter),
#"Expanded tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti_M2M" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti_M2M", {"ID_Aktivnost"}, {"tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti_M2M.ID_Aktivnost"}),
#"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti_M2M",{"tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti_M2M.ID_Aktivnost"},tblAktivnostiVsakodnevne,{"ID_aktivnost"},"tblAktivnosti",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded tblAktivnosti" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "tblAktivnosti", {"Aktivnost"}, {"tblAktivnosti.Aktivnost"}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded tblAktivnosti",{"ID_Podrocje_dela", "tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti_M2M.ID_Aktivnost"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Podrocje_dela"}, {{"Aktivnosti", each _, type table}}),
toList = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {"Aktivnosti", Table.ToList}),
output = #table(toList[Podrocje_dela],List.Zip(toList[Aktivnosti])),
#"Extracted Text After Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(output, {{"Finance", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, ","), type text}, {"IT", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, ","), type text}, {"Kadrovska", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, ","), type text}, {"Komerciala", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, ","), type text}, {"Podporne službe", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, ","), type text}, {"Proizvodnja", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, ","), type text}, {"Raziskave in razvoj", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, ","), type text}, {"Vodstvo", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, ","), type text}})
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody has the same problem. I found a solution to my problem. To have only single column grouped I specified which column to be specified:

from

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Podrocje_dela"}, {{"Aktivnosti", each _, type table}}),
```

to

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Podrocje_dela"}, {{"Aktivnosti", each _[Aktivnosti], type table}}),
```

The Power Query code with Ascending sort where nulls are at the end:

```
let
Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("\\fs-srv01\PROJEKTI\S-DELOVNI-PROCES\DELOVNE URE\MS_Access\Podatkovne_baze\Organizacija.accdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
_tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti = Source{[Schema="",Item="tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti"]}[Data],
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(_tblPodrocjaDela_Aktivnosti,{"ID_Podrocje_dela", "ID_Aktivnost"}),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"tblPodrocja_dela", "tblAktivnosti"}),
#"Expanded tblPodrocja_dela" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "tblPodrocja_dela", {"Podrocje_dela"}, {"Podrocje_dela"}),
#"Expanded tblAktivnosti" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded tblPodrocja_dela", "tblAktivnosti", {"Aktivnost", "Vsakodnevna"}, {"Aktivnosti", "tblAktivnosti.Vsakodnevna"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded tblAktivnosti", each true),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Aktivnosti", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"tblAktivnosti.Vsakodnevna"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Podrocje_dela"}, {{"Aktivnosti", each _[Aktivnosti], type table}}),
toList  = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Podrocje_dela", Order.Ascending}}),
MyColumnNames = toList[Podrocje_dela],
arrangedDataFromAccess = #table(MyColumnNames ,List.Zip(toList[Aktivnosti])),

SortAllColumns = Table.FromColumns(List.Generate(()=>
                [x=0,y=Table.Column(arrangedDataFromAccess  ,MyColumnNames{x})],
                each [x] < List.Count(MyColumnNames),
                each [x=[x]+1,y=Table.Column(arrangedDataFromAccess  ,MyColumnNames{x})],
                each List.Sort([y] ,(xx,yy)=>if xx&yy<> null then Value.Compare(xx ,yy) else Value.Compare(yy ,xx))),MyColumnNames),
    


CountItemsInColumns = List.Generate(()=>
                [x=0,y=Table.Column(arrangedDataFromAccess  ,MyColumnNames{x})],
                each [x] < List.Count(MyColumnNames),
                each [x=[x]+1,y=Table.Column(arrangedDataFromAccess  ,MyColumnNames{x})],
                each List.NonNullCount([y])), 
CountItemsInColumnsTransposed  = Table.Transpose(Table.FromList(CountItemsInColumns,Splitter.SplitByNothing()), MyColumnNames),

finalDataFromAccess = Table.Combine({CountItemsInColumnsTransposed, SortAllColumns}) in finalDataFromAccess
```